# Creating a Signed url on Gcloud using Rust

Tags: google-cloud-platform, rust

Trying to get signed urls working on GCloud, but can't seem to figure it out, documentation is complex.

Here's my attempt in Rust

```
fn signed_url(
    method: &str,
    object: &str,
) -> Result<String, Box<dyn std::error::Error>> {
    let expiration = Utc::now() + Duration::hours(1);
    let expiration = expiration.timestamp();

    let url_path = format!("/{}/{}", &env_vars().google_cloud_storage_bucket, object);
    let canonical_request = format!(
        "{method}\n{url_path}\n\nhost:storage.googleapis.com\nx-goog-algorithm:GOOG4-RSA-SHA256\nx-goog-credential:{}\nx-goog-date:{}\nx-goog-expires:{}\n\nhost;x-goog-algorithm;x-goog-credential;x-goog-date;x-goog-expires\nUNSIGNED-PAYLOAD", 
        env_vars().google_cloud_client_email, 
        Utc::now().format("%Y%m%dT%H%M%SZ"), 
        expiration
    );

    let rsa = Rsa::private_key_from_pem(env_vars().google_cloud_private_key.as_bytes())?;
    let pkey = PKey::from_rsa(rsa)?;
    let mut signer = Signer::new(MessageDigest::sha256(), &pkey)?;
    signer.update(canonical_request.as_bytes())?;
    let signature = signer.sign_to_vec()?;
    let encoded_signature = URL_SAFE.encode(signature);

    let signed_url = format!(
        "https://storage.googleapis.com{}?X-Goog-Algorithm=GOOG4-RSA-SHA256&X-Goog-Credential={}&X-Goog-Date={}&X-Goog-Expires={}&X-Goog-SignedHeaders=host&X-Goog-Signature={}",
        encode(&url_path),
        encode(&env_vars().google_cloud_client_email),
        Utc::now().format("%Y%m%dT%H%M%SZ"),
        expiration,
        encoded_signature
    );

    Ok(signed_url)
}
```

Comment: Update your question with a Signed URL and error messages. Create a test bucket and test object.